# VBA - Returning Range or Number from Applilcation.InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Applilcation.InputBox to get a number from the user. Further in the code I am multipying a range of cells with that number.

My problem is that I want to know if the number was written manually or chosen by selecting a cell in the worksheet (that means if the user has written „123“ then „123“ and if he has selected a range then return $A$1).

Code:

```
Dim output As Variant

Set output = Application.InputBox("Enter Number", "Number for multyplying")
```

Any advice, please?

Comment: I don't get your question. I'm pretty sure you cannot select any cells during the time InputBox prompt is active (which means users can't select any cells)

Comment: If you use the Application.Intupbox instead of InputBox (in VBA) you can select a range

Comment: I'm not able to replicate. If I choose a cell/range (which it allows me to do) I get a "Type Mismatch" error. UPDATE: looks like if I remove the `Set ` then it's happy. OP there is no way to determine if that `output` value was determined by selecting a cell or direct user input. It's just the value that is returned from `Inputbox`.

Comment: @MrZH6, if you are able to select a range and input a text/number in your input box, you are doing it Wrong. An input box without Type:=8, returns evaluated range value   not the range itself. Your best option is refedit on a userform. Flaky but works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. Either you set the type to 8, and then you can't enter numbers, or you set it to 1 and then you can't enter references. If you combine it to 9, you still have the problem with Set or no Set.

```
' Works for ranges
Set Output = Application.InputBox("Enter Number", "Number for multyplying", , , , , , 8)

' Works for literals
Output = Application.InputBox("Enter Number", "Number for multyplying", , , , , , 1)

' Could have worked for both, but it doesn't
Set Output = Application.InputBox("Enter Number", "Number for multyplying", , , , , , 9)
```

I think the cleanest way to solve this is to implement a UserForm with a RefEdit control.

Comment: Set Output on the last line fails because Output is not range but range value. e.g. if you have `=1+1`  in Cell A1 and you select it, what you get back is `2` and not `$A$1`

Comment: Thank you.

@cyboashu I see... so I have to replace the InputBox with an UserForm. With the RefEdit I am able to get both (range, if a cell is selected or Number which was typed in)? Never have used RefEdit in a UserForm, so I have to familiarize with that...

Answer (score 0):

So, with `Application.InputBox` I wasn't able to achieve the desired functionality, allthough I still think it's possible somehow... :-)

This is what I came up with (using a UserForm with RefEdit and other tools):

[image]

Pay no attention to the picture in the background. I was just trying out stuff... :-) Allthough, I quite like it after all :-)

And this is the code for the commandButton:
(ref_Input being the RefEdit, txb_number the TextBox)

```
Public gNmr As Variant

Private Sub cmd_OK_Click()
Dim adr As String

If ref_Input.Value <> vbNullString And txb_number.Value <> vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Choose just one option, please.", , "Wrong input"
    Exit Sub
Else
    If ref_Input.Value = vbNullString And txb_number.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "No input, please try again.", , "Wrong input"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If txb_number.Value = vbNullString Then
            adr = ref_Input.Value
            gNmr = adr
        Else
            If ref_Input.Value = vbNullString Then
            gNmr = txb_number.Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: You can combine the two inputs into one. Just add some IsNumeric testing, and I think you're set.

Comment: Oh, I see... I was testing that before, but I wasn't successful. Thats great! Thanks :-)